# the function keeps thinking im adding to methods when i want to add two integers

Tags: python

```
class Line:
    '''Fields: slope(anyof Int Float "undefined"), intercept (anyof Int Float)
          '''  

    def __init__(self,slope,intercept):
        self.slope = slope
        self.intercept = intercept

    def __repr__(self):
        s1 = "Y = {0:.2f}X + {1:.2f}"
        s2 = "X = {0:.2f}"
        s3 = "Y = {0:.2f}"
        if self.slope=="undefined":
            return s2.format(self.intercept)
        elif self.slope==0:
            return s3.format(self.intercept)
        else:
            return s1.format(self.slope, self.intercept)

    def __eq__(self, other):
            return type(other) == type(self) and self.slope == other.slope and \
                   self.intercept == other.intercept 

def intersect(self, other):

        '''
        intersect(self,other) return a list that contains two points that 
        represent the intersection of the two lines. False is returned if the 
        line are parallel or equal.

        intersect: Line((anyof Int Str Float),(anyof Float Int)
                   Line((anyof Int Str Float),(anyof Float Int)
                   -> (anyof Bool (listof (anyof Int Float) (anyof Int Float)))

        Examples:

            L1 = Line(1,3)
            L2 = Line(-1,3)
            L1.intersect(L2) => [0,3]

            L1 = Line(1,3)
            L2 = Line(1,3)
            L1.intersect(L2) => False
        '''


        if self.slope == other.slope:
            return False
        if self.slope == 0:
            if other.slope == 'undefined':
                return [other.intersect,self.intersect]
        if other.slope == 0:
            if self.slope == 'undefined':
                return [self.intersect,other.intersect]
        if self.slope == 'undefined':
            x = self.intersect
            y = (other.slope * x) + other.intersect
            return [x,y]
        if other.slope == 'undefined':
            x = other.intersect
            y = (self.slope * x) + self.intersect
            return [x,y]        
        if self.slope != other.slope:
            x = (other.intersect - self.intersect)/(self.slope - other.slope)
            y = (self.slope * x) + self.intersect
            return[x,y]

L5 = Line(1,10)
L6 = Line(0,5)
L5.intersect(L6)
```

i keep running into this error:

```
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'method'
```

Please help

Comment: Please paste the entire exception, with the traceback that says which line it's on, instead of just a description of it.

Comment: But `intersect` *is* a method. You need to call it if you want to get the return value.

Comment: I think i understand what i did wrong. I have been putting intersect instead of intercept. Thank you  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Comment: You might consider renaming the two to make them less similar. For example, `y_intercept` and `get_intersection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you were trying to do is:

On your last if, instead of intersect (which is a method indeed), you would be subtracting intercept, which is a value.

No ?

```
if self.slope != other.slope:
    x = (other.intercept - self.intercept)/(self.slope - other.slope)
    y = (self.slope * x) + self.intercept
    return[x,y]
```